# Is chain reaction possible in stable isotopes?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Is nuclear chain reaction possible in isotope that is considered stable? Are there examples?

Comment: U235 has a half-life of almost a billion years, so although it's not stable in the absolute sense, it's clearly right on the border, and in the practical sense it's "stable" enough to exist in the earth's crust. It's conceivable, although probably not likely, that there are nuclei in the transuranic island of stability that are stable. If so, then I'm sure they're fissile enough to undergo chain reactions.

Answer (score 2):

A chain reaction happens when an isotope, hit by a neutron, undergoes fission with more than one neutron being produced in the process - and where the neutrons produced have a sufficiently high probability of themselves creating further fission.

Now there is nothing in the above that requires the isotope to be unstable to begin with - as long as you hit it with the initial neutron that starts the reaction. In other words - you do need "kindling" for a chain reaction, but it might be sustained by fuel that is itself stable.

However, there is the little problem of the atoms that nature has actually made available. According to [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:C.A.T.S._CEO/List_of_fissile_nuclides), only Uranium (233, 235), Plutonium (239, 241), Curium (243, 245, 247) and Californium (251) are fissile - that is, they undergo fission when bombarded with thermal neutrons. That's a pretty short list - and none of them are "stable".

```
U-233  159 k years
U-235  704 M years
Pu-239  24.1 k years
Pu-241  14   years
Cu-243  29.1 years
Cu-245   8.5 k years
Cu-247  15.6 M years
Cf-251 900   years
```

I guess that means the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: This list is not complete. For instance, Neptunium-236 is missing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_neptunium#Neptunium-236 and others.

Comment: This table shows critical mass for some other isotopes (including americium): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_mass It seems the critical mass is not dependent on the half-life, but there is no stable isotope in the list. Why?

Comment: @Anixx - yes, the list I used as source (linked) is clearly incomplete. I hope others can contribute more information. Np-237 has a longer half life than Np-236 and higher probability of fission. It should be on the list too. Probably so should others.

Comment: I don't follow this answer: What is the characteristic that makes an isotope "fissile?"  That its nucleus can be split by a neutron "collision?"  Or can all isotopes with more than 1 neutron be split, and the characteristic that makes an isotope is "fissile" it that *when* split there is at least one neutron left unbound to either of the resulting nuclei?

Comment: @feetwet a fissile material has some reasonable probability of fission when hit with a (thermal) neutron, AND produces more than one neutron in the resulting decay (series). Just being able to disintegrate doesn’t make you “fissile” but just “fissionable”.

Comment: So for the first part: the unusual characteristic is that an isotope has a significant probability of *fission* from collision with a thermal neutron?  And is that characteristic strongly related to other nuclear characteristics?  Apparently it is *not* strongly related to either half-life or thermal-neutron cross-section, which would have been my first guesses.